# How to execute code from a child process in main process in Python?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, keyboard

I want to have a process that checks if a keyboard button is pressed and if it is then it sleeps the execution of the main process.

For example:

```
import time
import multiprocessing
import keyboard

def check_if_button_is_pressed(button):
    while True:
        if keyboard.is_pressed(button):
            time.sleep(100) # I want this line of code to run in the main function

def main():
    multiprocessing.Process(target=check_if_button_is_pressed, args=("g",)).start()

    while True:
        print("global execution")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

when g is pressed, I want it to stop printing "global execution" for 100 seconds.

Comment: This is not what you want, but you could have a flag variable `g_pressed`, set it to true before the sleep, then to false after, the `while True` loop technically continues executing but you can check the flag and not execute the part of the code you don't want to  if it's true.

Comment: Carefull. Threads are not processes. They are executed within the same process of the main thread.

Comment: If you want the main program (i.e., not your thread) to sleep then your sleep() call is in the wrong place. Even if you resolve that your naive approach is going to thrash your CPU. You might also want to consider tagging your question with Windows as the *keyboard* module doesn't work well on other platforms

Comment: @Itération122442 True, I have updated it to use processes instead of threads. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use some kind of communication. A go to thing is use a `Queue` to communicate between threads. It relies on the main thread polling the queue in the mainloop and reacting when something is in there.

In this case I made it so you put the time to sleep into the queue the main threads looks if something is in and if yes it uses the value as the input to the `time.sleep` function.

```py
import keyboard
import time
import threading
from queue import Queue, Empty

q = Queue()


def check_if_button_is_pressed(button, queue):
    while True:
        if keyboard.is_pressed(button):
            queue.put(100)
            time.sleep(0.1)  # Added since otherwise one keypress would add a lot of elements to the key


threading.Thread(target=check_if_button_is_pressed, args=("g", q)).start()

while True:
    try:
        ret = q.get(block=False)
    except Empty:
        ret = None
    if ret is not None:
        time.sleep(ret)
    print("global execution")
```